# send email without gmail

Tags: c#, email, com, gmail

It seems many solutions involve using a server: smtp.gmail.com and `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`.

- [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)
- [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677258/send-email-using-system-net-mail-through-gmail-c)

Other's suggest using `System.Web.Mail` (which many say has been deprecated):
[here for example.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/netfxnetcom/thread/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8)

In any case, when I tried it, I wasn't able to get either of the above examples to work.  I don't think it's a firewall problem.  I am able to use outlook express to send emails through gmail.   The error in C# that I am given is that the target machine is actively refusing the connection.

Should I attempt to use outlook from the code?   Would the best way to do that be through AutoIt or through some dll/com? Why do I need a server in the first place?  In C# I can download things from the web, why can't I just send specifically formatted webpackages (emails) directly from C#, without having to use some sort of server?

Comment: actually u need to host `SMTP` server or a service already established

Comment: could you explain what you mean by that?  Why is that necessary?

Comment: Whether it's strictly necessary varies by language/library, but email originating from just anywhere is typically blocked by some filters and large email hosts.

Comment: seems like they could just send that to a spam box but I guess it is what it is.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237159/sending-mail-works-on-server-but-not-on-my-local-machine) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might have to check out wireshark then. :-P

Answer (score 0):

you need smtp relay or gateway. I use http://sendgrid.com/ to send emails from the cloud, they have a free option.

there is also sample code on how to send emails, I re-factored their code so I could call it from other places.

```
public partial class Email
{
/// <summary>
/// Generic Email method used to send email through SendGrid
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ToAddressName">ToAddress, DisplayName</param>
/// <param name="FromAddress">Email address of sender</param>
/// <param name="FromName">Display Name of sender</param>
/// <param name="SendCopy">Send BCC to FromAddress</param>
public void SendEmail(Dictionary<string, string> toAddressName,
                      String fromAddress, String fromName,
                      String subject, String message,
                      bool sendCopy)
{
  try
  {
    MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

    // To
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in toAddressName)
    {
      string toAddress = kvp.Key;
      string displayName = kvp.Value;
      mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress, displayName));
    }

    // From
    mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName);

    if (sendCopy)
    {
      mailMsg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName));
    }

    // Subject and multipart/alternative Body
    mailMsg.Subject = subject;

    string html = message;
    mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

    // Init SmtpClient and send
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));

    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sendgridusername", "sendgridpassword");
    smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

    smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Error error = new Error();
    error.ReportError(ex);
  }
}
```

(ps if you have any comments on my code I would love to hear it, thanks)

Comment: If you want comments on your code I would recommend codereview at stackexchange.  Your code does look like it would work. Sorry, but this would lead to essentially the same problems as I had before.  I think it's a computer issue and not a code issue, although I don't EXACTLY know why.  So I'll probably end up trying wireshark or perhaps even a fresh install of the OS.